# Display issues with form control's Enabled property

Tags: ms-access

I have a form where a number of controls are greyed out (their Enabled property = False) until an associated control has been populated. I have two problems with this.

1. A control has text entered, it's On Update event sets the Enabled property of the associated control = True for data entry. If the user then presses Undo, the text comes out of the control but the associated control remains enabled. How to get this back to being Enabled = False when there is no longer data in the control?
2. When the user saves the record and moves to the next record to continue data entry, the state of the form is inconsistent. In some places controls are being displayed as they were at the end of the previous record, so if they'd been enabled during that data entry process then they are still enabled on the new record. Yet if you use the form to view the record saved, some control are back to being Enabled = False even though they contain saved data.

So how do I make sure that for a new record the controls are at their default setting for Enabled, but when viewing a record already entered they are correct for that record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may need to use the "On Lost Focus" event for your textboxes, and carry out a check at that point as to whether there is any data contained e.g:

```
Private Sub Text0_LostFocus()

    If Text0 & "" = "" Then
        Text0.Enabled = False
    Else
        Text0.Enabled = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure about that, after all, why check if there is no change?

Comment: @Remou Fair point, I think it's the way I read the question, it sounds as though Chelle wants to enable the textbox if the focus is set, but then set it back to disabled if no text is entered, so if the user clicks in and out without changing anything then no events would be fired normally but the Lost_Focus still would.

Comment: @MattDonnan: Thanks Matt, I found that by putting code in the LostFocus event it did indeed handle the situation when a user clicks 'Undo' and so removes the text in the field.

Comment: @Chelle Your welcome, if that is a satisfactory answer to your original question then please consider marking this as your accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Which events are you using? The controls should be set in the current event and in other events according to requirement. Do not forget you can say things like:

```
Me.txtText.Enable = (Me.txtOther = "abc")
```

EDIT re comments

```
If IsNull(Me.MyCombo) Then
     Me.MyText = Null
End If
```

Or

```
''Relevant column number starting from zero
Me.MyText = Me.MyCombo.Column(0)
```

Comment: I was using the Update event on one control to set the enabled property of the next. So if you select one of 10 hospitals from a combobox, the textbox for date attended is then enabled. So should I be using an event on the textbox itself to check what the value is in the combobox and enabled itself if it is anything other than an empty string?

Comment: Chelle I would only be guessing. I do not know what your program flow is and you have not posted any code, so I can only supply an outline. It sounds like you should be using the after update event of the combo to run a procedure and also the current event of the form t run the same procedure. For the most part, code that sets control properties needs to be run from more than one place.

Comment: I'll try that. Can I ask you another question? When a specific value is selected in another combobox I'm using the DLookup function to complete 3 other fields on the form. These are unbound as they're for information only and aren't saved back to the tables. When I click Undo the combobox is cleared but the values remain in the unbound textboxes. I've tried to use the combobox's Undo event to set the text of the unbound boxes to an empty string but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Just set the textboxes to null : `Me.MyTextbox=Null`

Comment: Adding the code from the control's Update event to the form's On Current event solved the first problem, Remou, so many thanks for that. Tried setting the textboxes to null if the combobox was empty or null but it didn't work.